# The KMPlayer ... playing with colors

Tags: kmplayer

*I'm not a video editing type, so go easy on me ... practically don't know anything on the subject*

except that for some videos I view, "color modifying" works (buttons `n`, `j`, `r` for reset ...) and for some it doesn't. What influences that and how can I incluence contrast, saturation and so on on every video I play?

*(mostly some recordings of experiments in poor light conditions, so those controls really come in handy when viewing some details before taking out snapshots for reports)*

Also, KMPlayer has an enormous number of options. Is there one somewhere that can take a snapshot in a predefined directory of the what-I-see-on-screen  every xy number of seconds?

Comment: Whats similar with these videos? What format are they?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - A variety of formats, .avi, .mp4, ...

Comment: If it works on some, and not others, working out whats the same about em would help hugely - I'd be less concerned with differences than similarities

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Wish I could help. I get them from three or four different coleagues. How could I tell what is similar about them?